# Does Nativescript WrapLayout has problem on iOS13?

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript

On my NS6 app whenever I open the page, BUTTONS inside Wraplayout are not visible but if I change the orientation then Its visible! Does anybody Know the reason ? I tried to comment out the WrapLayout and then Buttons are visible again.

```
<!--<WrapLayout class="m-l-10" orientation="horizontal" visibility="{{ isLight? 'collapsed' : 'visible' }}">-->
                       <GridLayout columns="50, *" marginTop="-5">
                           <Label col="0" text="&#xf05a;" class="h2 title rawInfoBtn font-awesome" marginBottom="0" tap="openInfo" verticalAlignment="top" horizontalAlignment="left" />
                           <Label col="1" text="{{_L('checklistlocation')}}" class="m-t-15" tap="openInfo" verticalAlignment="top" horizontalAlignment="left"/>
                       </GridLayout>
                   <Button text="&#xf067;  Neu" android:class="font-awesome raw-btn-android addBtn" ios:class="font-awesome roe-btn-ios addBtn" tap="addCheckList"/>
                   <Button text="&#xf019;  Importieren" android:class="font-awesome raw-btn-android addBtn" ios:class="font-awesome raw-btn-ios addBtn" tap="import"/>
                       <Button text="&#xf1d8;  Senden" class="font-awesome raw-btn-ios addBtn" tap="send"/>
                   <Button text="&#xf1e0;  Teilen" android:class="font-awesome raw-btn-android addBtn" ios:class="font-awesome raw-btn-ios addBtn" tap="share"/>
               *<!--</ *WrapLayout*>-->
```

Comment: Can you share a Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out only the `visibility` attribute only. Most probably the `isLight` property is causing the issue.